# How to specify path for cron script on SIteground?

Tags: path, cron, filepath

I manage a website on Siteground, and I want to run a cron script (I'm using the browser dashboard).
My script is present on the site, seen here in green in the file manager:

[image: File manager view]

I defined my cron script as `mysite.com/scripts/myscript.py` but the notification e-mail from the cron job informs me that `/bin/sh: mysite.com/scripts/myscript.py: No such file or directory`

How should I define the path to my script?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the path as below
‘/home/customer/www/mysite.com/public_html/scripts/myscript.py‘

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for the command enter the following

php -q /home/customer/www/mysite.com/public_html/scripts/myscript.py